# No data frame output out of script inside with() function

Tags: r, dataframe

I needed to create a new calculated secondary data frame out of a subset of a primary data frame. The best idea that came to mind was the following script, but there is no output ... lol!

```
set.seed(124)
avg_sum <- data.frame(diag_grp= c("benign", "malignant", "mixed"),
                         cc_ttl_avg= runif(3, min=10000, max=15000),
                         cc_ttl_drct_avg= runif (3, min=7000, max=10000),
                         cc_drct_srg_avg= runif (3, min=5000, max=7000),
                         cc_prof_drct_avg= runif (3, min=2000, max=5000),
                         cc_tech_drct_avg= runif (3, min=2000, max=5000),
                         dummy1= runif (3, min=1000, max=15000),
                         dummy2= runif (3, min=1000, max=15000),
                         dummy3= runif (3, min=1000, max=15000))


with(subset(avg_sum, diag_grp=="benign"),  
     {
     benign_avg_sum <-
       data.frame(rbind(c(key= "cc_ttl_avg", value= 
             paste(as.character(trunc(cc_ttl_avg/cc_ttl_drct_avg*100)), "% TDC", sep="")),
         c(key= "cc_ttl_drct_avg", value= 
             paste(as.character(trunc(cc_ttl_drct_avg/cc_ttl_drct_avg*100)), "% TDC", sep="")),
         c(key= "cc_drct_srg_avg", value= 
             paste(as.character(trunc(cc_drct_srg_avg/cc_ttl_drct_avg*100)), "% TDC", sep="")),
         c(key= "cc_prof_drct_avg", value= 
             paste(as.character(trunc(cc_prof_drct_avg/cc_ttl_drct_avg*100)), "% TDC", sep="")),
         c(key= "cc_tech_drct_avg", value= 
             paste(as.character(trunc(cc_tech_drct_avg/cc_ttl_drct_avg*100)), "% TDC", sep=""))))

     })
```

The expected output should be a data frame that looks like this:

```
               key    value
1       cc_ttl_avg 127% TDC
2  cc_ttl_drct_avg 100% TDC
3  cc_drct_srg_avg  75% TDC
4 cc_prof_drct_avg  34% TDC
5 cc_tech_drct_avg  52% TDC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the assignment outside of `with`.

```r
set.seed(124)
avg_sum <- data.frame(diag_grp= c("benign", "malignant", "mixed"),
                      cc_ttl_avg= runif(3, min=10000, max=15000),
                      cc_ttl_drct_avg= runif (3, min=7000, max=10000),
                      cc_drct_srg_avg= runif (3, min=5000, max=7000),
                      cc_prof_drct_avg= runif (3, min=2000, max=5000),
                      cc_tech_drct_avg= runif (3, min=2000, max=5000),
                      dummy1= runif (3, min=1000, max=15000),
                      dummy2= runif (3, min=1000, max=15000),
                      dummy3= runif (3, min=1000, max=15000))


benign_avg_sum <- with(subset(avg_sum, diag_grp=="benign"),  
     {
     data.frame(rbind(c(key= "cc_ttl_avg", value= 
                          paste(as.character(trunc(cc_ttl_avg/cc_ttl_drct_avg*100)), "% TDC", sep="")),
                      c(key= "cc_ttl_drct_avg", value= 
                          paste(as.character(trunc(cc_ttl_drct_avg/cc_ttl_drct_avg*100)), "% TDC", sep="")),
                      c(key= "cc_drct_srg_avg", value= 
                          paste(as.character(trunc(cc_drct_srg_avg/cc_ttl_drct_avg*100)), "% TDC", sep="")),
                      c(key= "cc_prof_drct_avg", value= 
                          paste(as.character(trunc(cc_prof_drct_avg/cc_ttl_drct_avg*100)), "% TDC", sep="")),
                      c(key= "cc_tech_drct_avg", value= 
                          paste(as.character(trunc(cc_tech_drct_avg/cc_ttl_drct_avg*100)), "% TDC", sep=""))))

     })

print(benign_avg_sum)
#>                key    value
#> 1       cc_ttl_avg 127% TDC
#> 2  cc_ttl_drct_avg 100% TDC
#> 3  cc_drct_srg_avg  75% TDC
#> 4 cc_prof_drct_avg  34% TDC
#> 5 cc_tech_drct_avg  52% TDC
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>